# How to increment an alphanumeric string in python?

Tags: python

I want to generate custom alphanumeric ID's.The following is the list i have,

```
DIS002533
DIS002534
DIS002535
DIS002535
DIS002536
DIS002537
```

I have to start generating from `DIS002538` for the next 300 items incremented by 1.Say,

```
DIS002539
DIS002540
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `zfill`  and you can generate string `002533` from `2533`

```
for n in range(2538, 2538 + 300):
    print ('DIS{0}'.format(str(n).zfill(6)))
```

also you can use (suggested by [JonClements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) from comments)

```
for n in range(2538, 2538 + 300):
    print('DIS{0:06}'.format(n))
```

Comment: `str(n).zfill(6)` is a little overkill here... you can amend your format, to be `print('DIS{0:06}'.format(n))` directly to get your leading zeros

Comment: @JonClements Your solution gives me the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

```
strr="DIS00"
num=2539
for i in range(300):
    print(strr+str(num))
    num+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ['DIS002533', 'DIS002534', 'DIS002535', 'DIS002535', 'DIS002536','DIS002537']
nums = [int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, x))) for x in mylist]
for n in range(max(nums) + 1, max(nums) + 302):
   print('DIS{0}'.format(str(n).zfill(6)))
```

Next `DIS002538`

Last `DIS002838`